# How to remove widget from RemoteViews in Android?

Tags: android, android-remoteview

I've a remote view which I it's layout is as follows :

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView id="1a"...>
    <TextView id="2a"...>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView id="1b"...>
    <TextView id="2b"...>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView id="1c"...>
    <TextView id="2c"...>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way I can programmatically remove one of the `TextViews` without removing the `View` it self ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I could find is setting the Widget to `visibility = GONE` :

```
remoteView.setViewVisibility(widgetID, View.GONE);
```